# red5 actionscript code examples

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mxml, red5

I am writing a Red5 application that provides  video chat to a Flash client over RTMP.

How to control the internet speed by reducing the clarity of the video transmission

Can any one please tell me where to look at the source for red5 with AS and mxml.

I have looked at the following links

http://www.red5chat.com/

&

http://www.red5chat.com/features-webcamchat.htm

Any links which would provide a brief tutorial would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

[you can build a hard wired one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gE-ihY_EG0) I am not sure it will work for you though the way you are intending.

[And apparently there are some plugins for you also.](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/11/throttle-bandwidth-of-firefox-and-ie/)